# Where to upload a User photo in the admin?

Tags: user-profile, settings

Not sure if I'm just overlooking, but I can't seem to find where in the admin to update my user photo (Craft versions 3.5 and 3.6).

The User Photo Location field in User Settings is set to a valid Volume, but when I view My Account (or edit the settings of any other Users) none of the Account/Permissions/Preferences tabs have a field to add/update this image.

I am logged in under an Admin account. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you go into Settings -> Users -> Settings, tap the Save button and see if that brings the fields back? You might think it's set but as far as Craft is concerned it might not be? I've seen this happen after removing an asset Volume.

Comment: @RitterKnight This was exactly it. I think it was the same trap too (removed an old asset volume). Once I hit Save I could see the changes on project.yaml where photoVolumeUid used to be `null`. Thanks!